# jQuery Hide and Show Divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello All at StackOverflow, over the last few days I have had some problems with my site and have got to a very comfortable point on where it is. My current jQuery script is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#firstpagename, #firstpagename2").click(function () {
        $("div#white").toggle();
    });

    $("#secondpagename, #secondpagename2").click(function () {
        $("div#v2black").toggle();
    });

    $("#thirdpagename, #thirdpagename2").click(function () {
        $("div#v3black").toggle();
    });
});
```

I know this might not be the cleanest and best method, but it works and has had me going crazy over the past 5 days as I have only start using jQuery for a week now.

What I am trying to do now is to make the div's ***white***, ***v2black*** and ***v3black*** open; and when it does open, it closes any of the other div's (see above) that might be open at the same time.

Here is my HTML incase it is needed for reference:

```
 <div class="altstevenav" style="display:none">
    <div class="stevenav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="#firstpagename" id="firstpagename">Steve A</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#secondpagename" id="secondpagename">Tattoos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thirdpagename" id="thirdpagename">Sketchbook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--MAIN CLOSING DIV-->
</div>
<!--CONTENT CLOSING DIV-->
    <div class="stevenav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="#firstpagename" id="firstpagename2">Steve A</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#secondpagename" id="secondpagename2">Tattoos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#thirdpagename" id="thirdpagename2">Sketchbook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<!--ALL DIVS ARE CLOSE HERE-->
<!--Divisional Panels-->
<div id="white">
<div style="width:968px; margin: 0 auto;">
<div class="panel" style="color:#000000;">
<div style="width:450px; float:left;">
<img src="<?php echo the_field('image_one_of_biography'); ?>" width="425" alt="Biography Image" />
<br /><br />
<img src="<?php echo the_field('image_two_of_biography'); ?>" width="425" alt="Biography Image" />
<br /><br />
<img src="<?php echo the_field('image_three_of_biography'); ?>" width="425" alt="Biography Image" />
</div>
<div style="width:450px; float:left; text-align:left;">
<?php echo the_field('biography_content'); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="v2black">
<div style="width:968px; height:1000px; margin: 0 auto;">

</div>
</div>

<div id="v3black">
<div style="width:968px; height:1000px; margin: 0 auto;">

</div>
</div>
```

I would like to think this is pretty simple, but would just like a bit of direction of how I should go about this..

**My question in a nut shell:** Only one div open at one time out of ***white***, ***v2black*** and ***v3black***.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642221/javascript-toggle-between-three-hidden-divs

Comment: Check out the jQueryUI Accordion.  That might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9474148/221619

Comment: it's actually a completely different question because I was at a completely different stage, and my questions we're not answered with the correct code or the correct 'method' of what I was after.

I have now solved it and would like to say thank you to those that helped. But i can assure you, this is not a duplicate question, so please read through both post's thoroughly as they are slightly different and at a different stages.

Comment: however - thank you for your help across other post's Alex - the problem is now solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign a common class and force them all closed on click then re-open the one you want...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#firstpagename, #firstpagename2").click(function () {
        $('.common').hide();
        $("div#white").toggle();
    });

    $("#secondpagename, #secondpagename2").click(function () {
        $('.common').hide();
        $("div#v2black").toggle();
    });

    $("#thirdpagename, #thirdpagename2").click(function () {
        $('.common').hide();
        $("div#v3black").toggle();
    });
});
```

Then add the class to html...

```
<div id="white" class="common">
</div>
<div id="v2black" class="common">
</div>
<div id="v3black" class="common">
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou very for your feedback, in some instances it did spit out the same information or stack the div's on top of eachother so it didn't work. However by combining code form all of you I have compiled this that work's perfect and is exactly what I am after!!

can't say how much this has done my head in, would like to say a massive thank you to all as you all got me to where I wanted to be.

Thank you for taking the time help me out! For anyone who is curious, the finished code that I used is below:

BOOM! Get in ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you probably want to look a jQuery [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) instead of using toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first one to:

```
$("#firstpagename, #firstpagename2").click(function () {
    $("#white").show();
    $("#v2black, #v3white").hide();
});
```

Then repeat for the others.

Comment: Thankyou very for your feedback, in some instances it did spit out the same information or stack the div's on top of eachother so it didn't work. However by combining code form all of you I have compiled this that work's perfect and is exactly what I am after!!

can't say how much this has done my head in, would like to say a massive thank you to all as you all got me to where I wanted to be.

Thank you for taking the time help me out! For anyone who is curious, the finished code that I used is below:

BOOM! Get in ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you give the elements that you want toggled a class (e.g. "toggleable"), it should work pretty easily:

```
$(".toggleable").click(function(){
      $(".toggleable").hide(); //Hide all elements with the class toggleable.
      $(this).toggle(); //Show the element that the user clicked on.
});
```

Comment: Thankyou very for your feedback, in some instances it did spit out the same information or stack the div's on top of eachother so it didn't work. However by combining code form all of you I have compiled this that work's perfect and is exactly what I am after!!

can't say how much this has done my head in, would like to say a massive thank you to all as you all got me to where I wanted to be.

Thank you for taking the time help me out! For anyone who is curious, the finished code that I used is below:

BOOM! Get in ;)